# Add value to integer array in C#

Tags: c#

How can I add a single Integer to an Integer Array?

```
 if (valuesHigherThanAverage.Length == 0) valuesHigherThanAverage[valuesHigherThanAverage.Length] = arrayGetal;
 else valuesHigherThanAverage[valuesHigherThanAverage.Length + 1] = arrayGetal;
```

I have this code and I have also tried with for or foreach loop but it doesn't worked. And I need to use an INT[] and may not use an List.

Comment: Arrays have a fixed size.

Comment: If you cannot use `List<>` then create new array which is 1 element bigger, assign old array and assign new value to the last element.

Comment: See `ArrayList` class. It can easily be transformed to normal array when necessary.

Comment: If your array is full and you need to add another value, you have to make a bigger array, copy all values, add the new one, then replace the first array with the new one.

Comment: What, pray tell, is wrong with a list?

Comment: `if (valuesHigherThanAverage.Length == 0)` that means that the array has **NO** element, which also means that you cannot access the element at position `0`! Generally this: `valuesHigherThanAverage[valuesHigherThanAverage.Length]` will always lead to an IndexOutOfBounds exception. Because `Length` is always 1 number larger than the maximum index you can use. Indexing starts at `0` and counting at `1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array is not designed to be extended as new elements are added. You will need to call `Array.Resize(Of T)` to increase the size but this is will be quite inefficient.

Data types more in line for what you want to do is `List<T>`.

Answer (score 3):

You can't add a new item in an array, you have to create a new array with size+1, copy all existing values, and then set the last item value.

An easier way is to use a `List<int>`, which will automatically resize if you run out of space. Calling the `Add` method suffices then.

Here a sample of an array resizing algorithm (`Array.Resize` could automate this, but this is just to show you how it should work):

```
int[] oldItems = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };

int[] newItems = new int[oldItems.Length * 2];

for (int i = 0; i < oldItems.Length; i++)
{
    newItems[i] = oldItems[i];
}

newItems[oldItems.Length + 1] = 4;
```

Comment: I'd recommend to increase the size not only by 1 but a little more. The exact number may be "inspired" by List implementation?

Comment: Indeed, I would use `*2`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the size of array like `valuesHigherThanAverage.Length + 1`. It has fixed size. You are crossing the upper bound of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Array with the length of the old array + 1.

```
public static int[] AddIntToArray(int[] sourceArray, int addValue)
{
    int[] newArray = new int[sourceArray.Length + 1];
    Array.Copy(sourceArray, newArray, sourceArray.Length);
    newArray[newArray.Length] = addValue;
    return newArray;
}
```